# Can a shrimp be a pet?

Tags: health, freshwater, water-parameters, invertebrates

I want to keep shrimp as a pet, but it would always be dead in about 1 or 2 days. I read lots of information and I know that it is lack of dissolved of oxygen.

How to get the water full of dissolved of oxygen?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can keep shrimps in your tank, but you will want to keep shrimps away from predatory fish if you want them to reproduce.

The first thing to do is to set up your tank and cycle it properly. You can take [a look here](https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm) on how this is done.

You need to get an [air driven sponge-filter](https://fishlab.com/sponge-filter/). This is to avoid shrimps or baby shrimps to be pulled into the filter, as might happen with other filter types.

The filter will build up bacteria that convert waste into plant nutrition and it will oxygenate the water.

You will need to have several plants in your tank; this is to provide hiding places for the shrimp and baby shrimp.

Plants will use some of the waste products in your tank and convert this into additional oxygen for your shrimps.

You will need to provide good lighting in your tank for the plants to produce oxygen. Good types are fluorescent light (type Grolux in your search engine or similar) or LED lighting.

Shrimps are very sensitive for ammonia and nitrite, so this have to be kept at zero in your tank,This is why you need to cycle your tank.

Shrimps do need very little food so remember not to feed them more than 2-3 times a week. Shrimps do mostly eat waste in your tank, which are bacteria-algae-dead plants and other organic waste.

You need to do weekly water changes 10-20% each week to keep pollution to a minimum in your tank and remember to use dechlorinator water treatment (ask in the petshop for this).

All of these are the minimum requirements for keeping shrimp in your tank and as you can see in this answer no metallic objects are in use inside the tank as almost all metals are toxic to shrimp.

Comment: Thank you. How Can I make a tank ? Is it Aluminum alloy or material?And how to produce oxygen water?

Comment: you need to get a real aquarium made of glass or acrylic material,the air driven filter will keep the water moving and this movement of the water will keep it oxygenated.all of the things i mention in my answer is important to understand and the cycling of the tank is the most important thing you need to do properly.never ever use a metalic tank for shrimp or fish.

Comment: I have a plan to get the water moving and the cycling.Is the acrylic better? I think the glass is easy to be broken.

Comment: why you recommend me not use a metallic for shrimp?

Comment: a metallic tank will release metall into the water and kill your shrimp they are very sensitive to any type of polutants.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you use a metallic tank? Aquatic pets are usually kept in transparent aquariums so we can look at them. This almost sounds like you want to breed them to eat them (sorry if I'm wrong, but I got the feeling from your question). If that's the case, be warned that it's very difficult to create the kind of environment to make shrimp breed. If you want to build your own aquarium, you need to use special aquarium glass because "normal" glass breaks. Keep in mind that water is heavy! You need to put your tank on a strong support.

Comment: @daotian what more do you want to know? i think i have covered what you need to know in my answer,water quality-filtration-environment-basic needs of shrimp.

Comment: I want to know how to build a water cycle system.make the water clear.and Can I keep them in a ceramics?

Comment: please read my answer and the links i provide it explain all you need to know about filtration and how to clean the water,you can use a plastic container made for food or water storage if you use ceramic it needs to be glazed.

Comment: what material of the tank is best? a ceramics/plastic/acrylic?

Comment: @daotian please read my last comment,use a container made for food/water the larger it is the better for your shrimps(it is easier to keep a good water quality in a larger tank)and setup a filtration system to keep the water clean and oxygenated.

Comment: @trondhansen how to disinfection? better physical but not too large and fit a small tank

Comment: use only clean water no chemicals,and remember to cycle the tank properly you will need to have a lot of good bacteria living in your filter.

Comment: I find that one day I take some water and some shrimps from a river the water is clear.but some hours later the water become muddy. just 2-3 hours . why? Is it because the NH3 or NH4?